# What? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /file/path

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, syntax-error

I am getting this error for the following line:

```
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey( $auth_args['consumer_key'], $auth_args['consumer_secret'] );
```

This is a wordpress template i just installed on a server. It works on my WAMP home server but not on the non self hosted server. Not sure if different PHP versions are the problem.

It is line 9 here:

```
class Jed_Widget_Latest_Tweets extends WP_Widget {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(false, $name = 'Jednotka Twitter Widget', array( 'description' => 'Twitter profile widget for your site.' ) );
}

function retrieve_tweets( $widget_id, $instance, $auth_args ) {

    if ( !empty($auth_args['consumer_key']) && !empty($auth_args['consumer_secret']) ) {
        \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey( $auth_args['consumer_key'], $auth_args['consumer_secret'] );
        $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
        $cb->setToken( $auth_args['access_token'], $auth_args['access_secret'] );
        $timeline = $cb->statuses_userTimeline( 'screen_name=' . $instance['screen_name']. '&count=' . $instance['num_tweets'] . '&exclude_replies=true' );
        return $timeline;
    }
    else {
        return 'Authentication to twitter server failed. Please make sure that your "consumer key" and "consumer secret" are not empty';
    }

}

function save_tweets( $widget_id, $instance, $auth_args ) {
    $timeline = $this->retrieve_tweets( $widget_id, $instance, $auth_args );
    $tweets = array( 'tweets' => $timeline, 'update_time' => time() + ( 60 * 5 ) );
    update_option( 'my_tweets_' . $widget_id, $tweets );
    return $tweets;
}

function get_tweets( $widget_id, $instance, $auth_args ) {
    $tweets = get_option( 'my_tweets_' . $widget_id );
    if( empty( $tweets ) OR time() > $tweets['update_time'] ) {
        $tweets = $this->save_tweets( $widget_id, $instance, $auth_args );
    }
    return $tweets;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your problem is PHP version. The PHP version on the other server likely doesn't support namespacing, so it doesn't know what to do about the backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you are using PHP 5.3 or higher, and that the namespace is declared, otherwise the interpreter is going to think \Codebird\Codebird is a random set of characters